# Connectivity error while connecting from "Aginity workbench for Redshift" tool to AWS Redshift cluster

Tags: odbc, amazon-redshift, sqlclient, aginity

I am trying to connect to a redshift cluster using aginity tool but see this below error.

[Error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCdiV.jpg)

I am able to connect to other cluster within the same aws account. The cluster to which I am able to connect is in "us-east-1" region. The cluster to which I am not able to connect is in "us-west-2" region. That is the only difference. All other parameters/configurations are same.

I verified inbound rules in security group, ssl-mode in redshift cluster parameter group and if redshift role was attached to the cluster. They are fine.

I tried googling the error message but it didn't help. I am stuck with this since a day. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, 08S01 is a network communications error. You've confirmed that the AWS side is properly configured, but do you have an on-prem firewall that could be causing an issue? One way you can test network connectivity is telneting to the instance port to confirm that it's reachable.

Have you tried using Aginity Pro, which uses the Redshift JDBC driver. One thing that's nice is you can copy the JDBC connection screen to the cli and isolate that the issue isn't with with application.